# How to get the value of a JSON token

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
"message":{
    "type":"text",
    "text":"a message to the service",
    "media":"http://example.com",
    "location":{
        "lat":50.76891,
        "lon":6.11499
    },
    "tracking_data":"tracking data"
}
```

How to get value of children element of Json, lat and lon?

```
JToken message = data.SelectToken("message");
 var lat = message.Value<double>("lat");
```

This shows 0, not real value.

Comment: Please show us what you have coded in C# so far, so we can see where you need help.

Comment: Please provide some code or the things you've done by yourself to solve this problem

Comment: JToken message = data.SelectToken("message");                                        var lat = message.Value<double>("lat");                                                         But it's shows 0, not real value

Comment: Please add your C# code to the question, it is not clearly visible and not expected in the comment section.

Comment: @Aleksandra that would be because your json structure is nested. `lat` is located beneath `location`. to access it you should first get the child location from message and then acces the child lat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick solution for this question is the following code.

The important point here is, that you have to respect the hirachical structure of your JSON input. `lat`is not directly in the `message`, but in the `location` object.

```
var data = JObject.Parse(@"{
        ""message"": {
            ""type"":""text"",
            ""text"":""a message to the service"",
            ""media"":""http://example.com"",
            ""location"": {
                ""lat"":50.76891,
                ""lon"":6.11499
            },
            ""tracking_data"":""tracking data""
        }
    }");

var location = data.SelectToken("message.location");
var lat = location.Value<double>("lat");
```